# PHP: Search if array contains values starting by a value

Tags: php, arrays, function, optimization

I have made a function to search an array and lookup for values starting by the 2d param :

```
  public static function arrayContainsValueStartingBy($haystack, $needle) {
      $len = strlen($needle);
      foreach ($haystack as $hay) {
          if (substr($hay, 0, $len) == $needle) {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
```

I feel like its not as optimized as it can be, could you give me some directions to improve it ?

Comment: see [`array_map()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score 2):

You have to profile the code to see whether it makes any difference (it could actually be worse, depending on the size of the strings you have), but you could use [`strpos` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) instead of `substr`:

```
public static function arrayContainsValueStartingBy($haystack, $needle) {
   foreach ($haystack as $hay) {
      if (strpos($hay, $needle) === 0) {
          return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Other than that I don't see much room for improvement. You have to iterate over the elements in any case, stopping as early as possible and you are already doing this.

Comment: `strpos` would check every position in the haystack, though, whereas with `substr` it only checks one position. So `substr` will be faster. Personally I can't think of how to make it better than the code in the question.

Comment: @Kolink: That's why I'm saying, it might be worse, depending on the size of the strings. I don't know the implementation of `strpos` and `substr` so running `strpos` might still be faster than creating a new string. Which code performs better really depends on the data in this case.

Comment: My $haystack contains 20 rows maximum of 5 chars approx.

Comment: @mnml: And what is the size of the needle? But with such a small data set, I don't think you will see any difference in the performance.

Comment: @felix The needle will always be 2char long

Comment: @mnml: In that case you could even try to compare the characters directly: `$hay[0] === $needle[0] && $hay[1] === $needle[1]` (which makes the function more specific though). But I don't know whether this will be faster, just making suggestions ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the looping would be faster using array_filter:

```
$testArray = array('Hello',
                   'World',
                   'Aardvark',
                   'Armadillo',
                   'Honey Badger'
                  );

$needle = 'A';


class beginsWith {
    private $_needle = NULL;

    function __construct($needle) {
        $this->_needle = $needle;
    }

    public function filter($string) {
        return (strpos($string, $this->_needle) === 0);
    }
}


$matches = array_filter($testArray, array(new beginsWith($needle), 'filter'));


var_dump($matches);
```

Though instantiating the beginsWith class probably adds overhead.